# How can I pass PHP variables value to Client Code for Paypal

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

I am trying to integrate Paypal with my website and facing issues with this. The problem is that I cannot seem to find a way to send the PHP variables value, that is the TOTAL AMOUNT to Paypal code

Suppose I have a variable

```
$finalAmount = 220;
```

This value is dynamic and will change with each user. I need to pass it below inside the Paypal code

```
<script>

        paypal.Button.render({
          // Configure environment
          env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

           // PayPal Client IDs - replace with your own
           // Create a PayPal app: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create
          client: {
            sandbox: 'CODE_HERE',
        //    production: 'demo_production_client_id'
          },
          // Customize button (optional)
          locale: 'en_US',
          style: {
             layout: 'vertical',  // horizontal | vertical
             size:   'medium',    // medium | large | responsive
             shape:  'rect',      // pill | rect
             color:  'gold'
          },
          // Set up a payment
          payment: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.create({
              transactions: [{
                amount: {
                  total: '1',
                  currency: 'USD'
                },
                invoice_number : 123111241, // invoice must be unique for each transaction.
                item_list: {
                      items: [
                      {
                        name: 'hat',
                        description: 'Brown hat.',
                        quantity: '2',
                        price: '3',             
                        sku: '1',
                        currency: 'INR'
                      },
                      {
                        name: 'handbag',
                        description: 'Black handbag.',
                        quantity: '1',
                        price: '7',             
                        sku: 'product34',
                        currency: 'INR'
                      }
                    ],
                    shipping_phone_number : '8888888888',
                    shipping_address: {           
                      recipient_name: 'Logan loga',
                      line1: '4th Floor',
                      line2: 'Unit #34',
                      city: 'Chennai',
                      country_code: 'IN',
                      postal_code: '600113',
                      phone: '9999999999',
                      state: 'Tamil Nadu'
                }
                }       
              }],
              payer: {
                payment_method: "paypal",
                payer_info : {
                email: 'test@gmail.com',
                first_name :'Logan',
                last_name  :'loga',
                billing_address : {                       
                      line1: '4th Floor',
                      line2: 'Unit #34',
                      city: 'Chennai',
                      country_code: 'IN',
                      postal_code: '600114',
                      phone: '7777777777',
                      state: 'Tamil Nadu'
                }       
                }
             },
            });
          },
          // Execute the payment
          onAuthorize: function (data, actions) {
            return actions.payment.execute()
              .then(function (res2) {
                // Show a confirmation message to the buyer
                console.log(res2);
                console.log(res2.transactions[0].related_resources[0].sale.state);
                //state codes - completed, partially_refunded, pending, refunded, denied
                if(res2.transactions[0].related_resources[0].sale.state == 'completed'){
                alert("Payment received for the invoice number" + res2.transactions[0].invoice_number); 

                }   
              });
          },
          onCancel: function (data, actions) {
            // Show a cancel page or return to cart
            alert("Payment  cancelled");
          },
           onError: function (err) {
            // Show an error page here, when an error occurs
            alert("Payment  error");
          }
        }, '#paypal-button');
        </script>
```

I want to pass the value of $finalAmount to the PayPal script at

```
amount: {
   total: 'HERE'
}
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: Remember that javascript is client side. If you have the amount to be paid in your javascript then anyone with a little web development experience can edit this amount and pay way less (ore more?) than they should.

Comment: @DirkScholten any tips you'd like to give to me to avoid this thing?

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact flow of your website is. But at some point you will have to tell paypal about the payment. At this point you should use PHP to query your database for the price. If you get this value from your javascript there will always be a chance that a user has edited the value.

Comment: Is it just me or is the whole Client Integration scheme horribly insecure? All the credentials, order details, callback URLs, etc, are sitting there vulnerable to be edited, replayed, etc... Is there an example anywhere of a real-world implementation of client side integration that is secure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can use...
`amount: {
   total : '<?php echo $finalAmount ?>'
}`

Comment: i tried this, its not working. This was my first try

Answer (score 0):

create a new hidden input field with a unique id and get the value of that field in js. for example

In your PHP  Page :

`<input type="hidden" id="finalAmount" value="<?php echo $finalAmount ?>">`

In Your js code :

```
var finalAmount = $('#finalAmount').val();
```

Hopefully, you will get the amount you are looking for :)